# Shell scripting add slashes in file name with space

Tags: command-line, scripts, unzip

I am a newbee and want to write a shell script in which I will look up in a certain directory for zip file and unzip it to certain directory.

File name can have spaces like this "Harry's 20 july.zip"

I am getting error when I am trying to unzip using below command:-

```
unzip "$source_file" -P$password -d $destination_directory
```

I already enclosed in double quotes but dont know how to add slashes in $source_file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you passing in the filename as an argument to the script?

Comment: I am giving this script to non technical person, in which he will replace the variable values with zip file name which can be different every time.

Comment: He will be doing that manually? O.o

Comment: Yes, just changing the name of file because directory can have multiple zip files which he might not be interested in extracting

Comment: Then you can tell him to keep the quotes. The command as it stands handles spaces in the source filename, so your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: unzip "$source_file" -P$password -d $destination_directory can be changed to unzip "$source_file -P$password -d $destination_directory" ?

Comment: No. Then you are passing the whole of `$source_file -P$password -d $destination_directory` as the name of a file to `unzip`.

Comment: I understand, basically this is the problem. I am wondering how can I achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15904/discussion-between-muru-and-jatin-dhoot).

Comment: You can delete your question yourself if you want.

Answer (score 1):

It was related to ordering of params.

As assisted by @Muru ordering should be

```
 unzip -P$password "$source_file" -d "$destination_directory"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are answering it, you might as well write a full answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: Added answer in this

Comment: Please mark it as accepted as well. :)

Comment: It says "You can accept your answer in 21 hours", thats why I was not able to accept